# Is there an adjectival form of "recipe"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, derivational-morphology

Is it possible to use "recipe" as an adjective as in the following sentence:

> These are some **reciptial** suggestions for you.
>   (These set of suggestions are like a recipe to your problems.)

What other word can I use if the example above is erroneous?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no common adjective formed from *recipe*. There might be an uncommon one listed in some dictionaries, but the OED has neither *recipial* nor *recipital*.

However, English allows us to use nouns as noun modifiers in many cases. *Recipe ideas* and *recipe suggestions* are both familiar phrases, but they mean *ideas for recipes* etc, which is not what you are talking about.

In fact, your *recipe to your problems* does not make sense to me: a *recipe* in its transferred sense is a set of steps to achieve something; that is different from a *solution* to a problem. You would have to say something like

> Here are some suggestions which may give you a recipe for solving your problems.

Answer (score 3):

From recipe's synonyms you can use:

"Formulaic"

Or

"Prescriptive"

**These are some formulaic suggestions for you.**

**These are some prescriptive suggestions for you.**

> Main Entry: rec·i·pe  Pronunciation: \ˈre-sə-(ˌ)pē\ Function: noun
>   Etymology: Latin, take, imperative of recipere to take, receive — more
>   at receive Date: 1584 1 : prescription 4a 2 : a set of instructions
>   for making something from various ingredients 3 : a formula or
>   procedure for doing or attaining something

From Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary

Comment: And "algrithmatic".